# Nodes in blender cancel my texture

Tags: mapping, textures, blender, mesh

I have a 3d mesh in blender, textured with UV mapping.
I would like to add some material effects like wood with nodes, so I went to the node editor, but clicking on "use nodes" my mesh turn yellow (there's a yellow color applied to my mesh).

How can I do to apply UV mapping and material to my mesh?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the blender internal render engine. While this has support for [node based materials](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/index.html), development of it was limited and it wasn't something that caught on much, so you will not find much in the way of tutorials.

To use a texture you will need to add a texture node and select the texture you setup before, most likely a geometry node to get the uv's and connect them to the output.

[image: internal material nodes]

You will find that the newer Cycles render engine is fully node based and has much better support and [documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/index.html) with a larger range of nodes available.